# Unable to upload with FPM/FastCGI

Tags: php

I'm unable to upload an image using html & php, I managed to trace the issue to FPM/FastCGI because when I locally(xampp) switched it to Apache 2.0 Handler it works correctly. However on the server I only have access to the cpanel and cannot switch the server API.

In the form I'm using `multipart/form-data` and this php class https://www.verot.net/php_class_upload.htm to handle the uploads. When I submit the form I get access forbidden.

Below is a screenshot of the phpinfo of the server

[image]

**The error I get:**

````
You don't have permission to access this resource.
Additionally, a 403 Forbidden
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.```
````

Comment: Access forbidden? Does the whole page say that? A 403 error? Or does it mention to what you don't have access?

Comment: If it is a 403 HTML error you should check the file permissions of the PHP file to which you sent the uploaded files.

Comment: the permissions are fine, if I remove ```multipart/form-data``` the form works but without the uploaded images